# How may I determine the cxxabi before loading a shared object with dlopen()?

Tags: c++, c

I would like to determine that I am loading a compatible binary before calling dlopen().  I want to determine the cxxabi level before I load the library.

Answer (score 1):

You could scan the list of symbols used by the binary before opening it. I am not sure how to do this in a program, although you can read the source for `readelf` for hints.

Using `readelf -d -s -W /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | c++filt | less` on a Linux system I see some symbols marked like this: `__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()@@CXXABI_1.3`

However, I would probably just try `dlopen()` and if it returns NULL, use `dlerror()` to report an error, then let the user figure it out.

Comment: I will try studying the source code.  dlopen() isn't sufficient. Because I have no control over the s. o. modules I load, it is possible to load one that uses libstdc++.so.6 and one that uses libstdc++.so.5.  dlopen() will load them both just fine, but bad things may or may not happen later on.  More often they will.